# Difference between Geometry & Polygon functions- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Studying for the 70-461 and my book (Joes2pro Vol3) makes no mention of a difference between `STGeomFromText` & `STPolyFromText` functions, though it reads like there is a discernible difference between the two.

Examples asked to run are here

```
Select Geometry::STGeomFromText('Polygon ((0 0, 28 0, 28 21, 0 21, 0 0))',0)

Select Geometry::STPolyFromText('Polygon ((0 0, 28 0, 28 21, 0 21, 0 0))',0)
```

Which gives me exactly the same output and Microsoft docs is a little light on the subject for both these functions. All I can screen out is one is a geometry instance and the other is a `geometryPolygon` instance ?

Can anyone tell me when one is used over the other and what the above actually means ?

Kind regards,

SQLBoffin.

Answer (score 0):

`STGeomFromText()` will take the WKT for any type of geometry (polygons of course but also points and lines) whereas `STPolyFromText()` will only do polygons.

Comment: Great thanks for your response. So really the STGeomFromText() function is basically just  the combination of the STPointFromText(), STLineFromText() and STPolyFromText(). For some reason I was expecting the answer to be more complicated but ill take it. Cheers